# Sql selecting distinct in where

Tags: sql, select

i am attempting to make a sum select:

```
select sum(price) as 'total', currency_id
from reports
group by currency_id
```

but the table contains a row called transaction_id, once counting the sum i would like to only count rows that have a distinct transaction_id value, how can i create this where?

Comment: Could you please share sample data and desired output

Comment: `select sum(price) as 'total', currency_id, transaction_id from reports group by currency_id, transaction_id`

Comment: 1) provide sample data and desired output 2) tag your database

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "count rows that have a distinct transaction_id value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count each transaction id once, then you can use window functions:

```
select sum(price) as total, currency_id
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by transaction_id order by transaction_id) as seqnum
      from reports r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1
group by currency_id;
```

If you want to sum `transaction_id`s that appear only once, you can still use window functions, but with a difference:

```
select sum(price) as total, currency_id
from (select r.*,
             count(*) over (partition by transaction_id) as cnt
      from reports r
     ) r
where cnt = 1
group by currency_id;
```